# Kotlin Selenium lateinit List of WebElements not being initialized

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm building a selenium test using a POM, and I have a List of Webelements (companyNames in SelectAccountPage) that keeps throwing a UninitializedPropertyAccessException.

Here's the Page Object

```
class SelectAccountPage(driver: WebDriver) {

@FindBy(css = "header h2")
lateinit var selectAccountTitle: WebElement

@FindBy(css = "div[class*='company-picker'] h3")
lateinit var companyNames: List<WebElement>

init {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)
}

fun pickCompany(companyToSelect: String) {
    for (company in companyNames) {
        if (company.text == companyToSelect) {
            company.click()
        }
    }
}
```

and the test

```
class SignInTest : TestBase() {

    lateinit var signInPage: SignInPage
    lateinit var forgotPasswordPage: ForgotPasswordPage
    lateinit var selectAccountPage: SelectAccountPage

    @BeforeTest
    fun initPageObjects() {
        signInPage = SignInPage(driver)
        forgotPasswordPage = ForgotPasswordPage(driver)
        selectAccountPage = SelectAccountPage(driver)
        assert = SoftAssert()
    }

   @Test(priority = 3)
    fun validCredentials() {
        driver.get(signInPage.url)
        signInPage.sendCredentials(Config.getUser(), Config.getPassword())
        assert.assertTrue(driver.currentUrl.contains("app"))
        selectAccountPage.pickCompany("Generic")
        assert.assertAll()
    }
```

I'm not sure what's going on here because the Webelement on the same page is initialized just fine. Is there something specific that needs to be done when initializing Lists?

Comment: Hi Kevin. I stumble upon this similar issue with Appium. Kindly check if the workaround helps https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1257#issuecomment-583542566

Comment: Nope, looks like an ArrayList can't be passed to the PageFactory.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably already found an answer, but I am leaving it just in case somebody else came across this problem, as I did to today.

```
@FindBy(css = "div[class*='company-picker'] h3")
val companyNames: List<WebElement>? = null
```

Changing code as above did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use MutableList instead of List

so you will have:

`lateinit var companyNames: MutableList<WebElement>`

Comment: Could you please edit this answer to explain why `MutableList<WebElement>` will work better for the OP than `List<WebElement>`.